# Pylint ignore file with git-pylint-commit-hook

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit-hook, alembic, pre-commit

Im using [pylint 1.6.4](https://www.pylint.org/) and [git-pylint-commit-hook 2.1.1](https://github.com/sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook)  to lint my files on pre-commit. I also use [alembic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic) to generate my migrations, they are stored in `<project-root>/migrations/versions`.

The problem is that the generated migrations are not valid and pylint generates a warning for them. I can ignore migrations with --ignore=migrations. (Pylint ignores them by default anyway because migrations isn't a python module, it's simply a directory). But git-pylint-commit-hook calls pylint with list of changed files to validate. And pylint doesn't check if the file should be ignored if you give it a list of filenames, not modules.

This causes the pre-commit hook to fail when there is a new migration to be commited.

```
Running pylint on migrations/versions/d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table.py (file 2/13).. 8.6/10.00   FAILED
************* Module d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table.py
C:  5, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
C:  1, 0: Invalid module name "d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table" (invalid-name)
C: 16, 0: Import "from alembic import op" should be placed at the top of the module (wrong-import-position)
C: 17, 0: Import "import sqlalchemy as sa" should be placed at the top of the module (wrong-import-position)
C: 20, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C:171, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
```

I tried to add `#pylint: skip-file` to beginning of each migration file. This skips the file but generates and error that the file was skipped:

```
Running pylint on migrations/versions/d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table.py (file 2/13).. 0/10.00 FAILED
************* Module d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table.py
I:  1, 0: Ignoring entire file (file-ignored)
```

So I tried to ignore error `file-ignored` in .pylintrc like this:

```
[messages control]
disable=unused-argument
```

It works and the error is no longer reported but pre-commit hook fails because it doesn't find any statements:

```
Running pylint on migrations/versions/d1f0e08ea6d2_skill_table.py (file 2/13).. 0/10.00 FAILED

Report
======
0 statements analysed.
```

Notice that in both cases pylint evaluates the files as 0.0/10.0 so setting lower threshold for failure isn't the solution.

**The question is, how do I make git-pylint-commit-hook and pylint to ignore my migrations?**

Comment: Would this fix be of help to you? https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1079 This means that pylint can start ignoring files which were passed as a list of filenames, rather than a package. Also, you probably shouldn't care about the Informational category (I), it can be disabled with --disable=I (and this will be by default in Pylint 2.0).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your solution and unfortunately it doesn't work. `should_analyze_file()` is never called when I run pylint with filename. It gets called only when I run pylint with module name.

Comment: Can you provide an example on the issue? Do note though that even with that example, there is still a small change to be made in the call site of should_analyze_file (https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylint/lint.py#L831). Currently it is called only if the file is *not* an argument, which means ``pylint a.py`` will not trigger it, but ``pylint pkg/`` where ``a.py`` is part of ``pkg`` will trigger it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So git-pylint-commit-hook basically calls `pylint migrations/versions/somefile.py`. Migrations and versions are directories without __init__.py. So putting git-pylint-commit-hook aside, I need pylint to ignore somefile.py even if I put it give it as arguments. Or to report 10/10 when the whole file is ignored with `#pylint: skip-file` (not statements found).

Or I have to find solution within git-pylint-commit-hook.

Let me test something and create a working example.

Comment: I tested it (by modifying the example code you gave me) and unfortunately, even if pylint ignores the file, git-pylint-commit-hook can't handle it. When it sends file to pylint it expects it to be analyzed. If pylint doesn't analyze the file, git-pylint-commit-hook crashes. So this "bug" is in fact in the commit-hook, not in pylint:

```
$ git commit -m "test"
Running pylint on tools/linter.py (file 1/1).. 
An error occurred. Is pylint installed?
```

The modification was simply giving pylint different file than the one from commit: `CustomRun(['app.py'])`

Comment: Okay, I think in this case the issue can be brought to git-pylint-commit as well. In the mean time, I'll provide a fix on Pylint's side, so if anyone needs should_analyze_file overridden, they could do so in all the cases.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but I have just ran into this issue myself. I found the answer while searching [this](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/395) thread.

To solve this problem, just add an `exclude` directive with a regex that matches your folder.

If you want to exclude the migrations folder, by example, just add:

`exclude: ^tests/`

To your Pylint settings. Mine looks like this:

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: system
        name: PyLint
        entry: poetry run pylint
        language: system
        exclude: ^alembic/
        files: \.py$
```

Comment: Wow that's a very elegant solution, Felipe!